# Installing 15.04 on 32 bit machine under VMWare Workstation 10

Tags: 15.04, login, vmware, 32-bit

I am trying to install ubuntu 15.04 on a laptop running VMware workstation 10.  It is a 32bit machine with 1GB memory (Yes it's really old).  I get through the install without issue and system boots up to login gui.  When I type in my password to login it starts like it is opening the desktop. Cursor spins then screen goes black and pops back up to login again.  I know that I have the password right.  Any ideas how to get past this?    I also tried installing 14.04.3 and got the same exact results

Answer (score 0):

Please check [{HERE}](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) and see if your Laptop meets the minimum requirements. Unless it a custom built, or modified, I believe your Laptopt is what I would refer to as jurassic, and will not be able to run Ubuntu.